# Recover Powerdesigner auto save file 16.7

Tags: powerdesigner

Powerdesigner crashed and I can't find my files.
Under General Options > General
I set "Save recovery backup file" to every 5 minutes but cannot find any recovery file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my test, I saw a directory created as `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\PowerDesigner\16.7\AutoSaveFolder\`.

After shooting, and restarting PowerDesigner, I got a confirmation dialog:

```
---------------------------
Restore Recovery Backup File
---------------------------
A previous PowerDesigner session exited abnormally.

Do you want to restore the backup file?
---------------------------
Yes   No   
---------------------------
```

According to the documentation, this applies to "all open models". And in my test, nothing happened for a new model, until I had saved it once.